# Is it possible to get emails that are in junk/spam folder(bounced or Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender) in Gmail?

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have a question about bounced or Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender!

Is it possible, in PHP, to retrieve/get emails that are in the SPAM/JUNK folder in Gmail (G-suite)

I have a lot of "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" or "postmaster..." and so I want to fix that.

I found this: https://github.com/voku/PHPMailer-BMH

But I always receive this error:

> imap_open(): Couldn't open stream

And:

> Cannot create imap connection to imap.gmail.com
> Error MSG: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)

I also tried without this library and only use imap_open:

```
$connection = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'me@mydomain.com', 'MyPassword') ;//or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

And I got this error :

> Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
>
> Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
> (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials
> (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials
> (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Unknown: Too many login failures (errflg=2) in Unknown
> on line 0

### Solution

I found this: https://www.getmailbird.com/setup/access-gmail-com-via-imap-smtp

To enable IMAP for less secure app in Gmail account security settings.
After I enabled it, all works perfectly!

Comment: You should be able to use IMAP to connect to Gmail. See https://www.getmailbird.com/setup/access-gmail-com-via-imap-smtp

Comment: Please show what you tried.